# Blocked contact and multitasking menu iOS 8

Tags: contacts, ios

What happens if I call or send a message to a contact I have blocked?

Does that contact show up on the recent contacts multitasking menu?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Even messages to blocked contacts display that blocked contact in "Recent" in the app switcher.

You can disable the "Recents" altogether if you would like. Go to Settings -> Mail, Contacts, and Calendar -> Show In App Switcher (under Contacts).